# Can't make file as executable form

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, chmod, apple

i've install Ubuntu as second os on my Macbook Pro.
When i was installed my Ubuntu, im choose the ext4 partition for whole OS.But now it's NTFS, so i can't make any file executable through the chmod +x command, but for other write,read operations it's okay.
For example chmod 777 file works perfectly except the execute option.
How can i change the partition without losing any data?

```
NAME    FSTYPE     LABEL        UUID                               MOUNTPOINT 
sda 
├─sda1  vfat       EFI          70D6-1701                           /boot/efi 
├─sda2  hfsplus    Новый        43718f19-c67d-3ff3-b34f-fcc0c56950df 
├─sda3  hfsplus    Recovery HD  6130b4eb-7738-32e0-841b-3098ffb4c1d5 
└─sda4  ext4                    9ae7d19f-de4f-4b7a-853b-96b21d3c6efd /
```

Comment: Please run this command and post outpu `lsblk -f`

Comment: hmm it's ext4.. here's image                                                                                                     https://ibb.co/jx7Cek

Comment: Please copy and paste that output into the post

Comment: NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                             
├─sda1 vfat    EFI         70D6-1701                            /boot/efi
├─sda2 hfsplus Новый       43718f19-c67d-3ff3-b34f-fcc0c56950df 
├─sda3 hfsplus Recovery HD 6130b4eb-7738-32e0-841b-3098ffb4c1d5 
└─sda4 ext4                9ae7d19f-de4f-4b7a-853b-96b21d3c6efd /

Comment: How did you get to know it was `NTFS`?

Comment: i asked this question to google, and read some topic with the same problem, and all of solutions be like this " just copy your file to home directory because NTFS Didn't support permissions, but this don't work for me

Comment: Please can you show the exact command you used to make executable file!

Comment: i'm use the chmod +x myprogramm.sh